# BeanUtils / PropertyUtils reading nested "collection"

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

Searching through google, SO couldn't find me a solution, so here's my problem -

I have a class `Employee` with a nested collection `addresses` of type `java.util.Set`. The structure looks like below

```
class Employee {

   private Set<Address> addresses;   

}

class Address {

  private String street;   

}
```

I would like to use Apache's `BeanUtils` or `PropertyUtils` to read the `street` property of the first `Address` object within the `Employee` object if exists. If the `addresses` set is `null` or empty, I should get the value `null` from the API. Can anyone please help me with the `BeanUtils` way of doing that?

**What I have tried?** -

```
BeanUtils.getProperty(e, "addresses.street"); 
BeanUtils.getProperty(e, "addresses[0].street"); 
BeanUtils.getProperty(e, "addresses.get(0).street"); 
BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(e, "addresses.street");
```

None of them worked.

Comment: Can you use `List` instead of `Set`? I've looked in to source code [as in here](https://github.com/apache/commons-beanutils/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils2/PropertyUtilsBean.java#L537) BeanUtils only supported to `List` of `String` only via `BeanUtils.getIndexedProperty(employee, "addresses", 0);`

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan yes you are absolutely right! Looks like BeanUtils only supports indexed collection.. like `ArrayList` or plain array..